# How can I find to starting point of skewed data in python?

Tags: python, statistics, seaborn

I have a list like this,

```py
import random
import seaborn as sns

years = []

for i in range(1000):
    if i % 100 == 0:
        val = random.randint(1900, 2000)
    else:
        val = random.randint(2000, 2021)

    years.append(val)

sns.distplot(years);
```

Here is output graph,
[image: Distplot]

As you can see, there is a density after 2000. There is not much data before this point. My question is how can I find this point in skewed data? Is there a formula that gives this? Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the level of what you want, I would suggest to just start with removing the the data with lower count :

- Bin your data (equivalent to what you did by plotting the histogram)
- Count the value in each bin
- Look at the distribution of such values.
- Remove the lowest counts
- Get the cut off as the min of what is remaining
- Try different bin size

That should cover getting the value.

Then you may want to make some assumption on the underlying process then try some statistical test on data before / after to see if the difference is significant.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at ways to find outliers, such as Tukey's fences or the modified Thompson's tau.